# How to Create an IF statement to see what the data table contains by C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem to create an if statement to see what the datatable contains.

I create Ticket Reservation System, and I created a query sentence to know the numbers of seats that were reserved by this code:

```
 private void Selected_Chair()
    {
        if (label14.Text != "ــــ" && label16.Text != "ــــ" && label19.Text != "ــــ" && label21.Text != "ــــ")
        {
            SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("select Seat_Number from Booking where Date_Travel='" + bunifuDatePicker1.Text + "' and Start_Station='" + label14.Text + "' and Time_Start='" + label19.Text + "' and End_Station = '" + label16.Text + "' and Time_End ='" + label21.Text + "'", sqlcon);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ada.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Now, How do I know what the seat numbers contain in the data table?, so that I can color the seats that have been reserved.
[Picture of the shape of the seats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NsAC.png)

Comment: Please don't forget to read up and understand what "SQL Injection vulnerability" means.

Comment: I encourage you to spend some time reviewing [the documentation for DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0) and its properties. You have to learn how to access rows and columns rather than starting with "know what seat numbers contain".

Comment: Have you tried looping through the `DataTables` rows collection? … something like… `foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) { … int seatNumber = (int)Row[“Seat_Numner”]; … };`